# I'm trying to integrate Intercom into a meteor app using verso:intercom

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, single-page-application, intercom

Ok, so I've integrated it and it's working fine at a basic level but I have 2 related problems....

Firstly, where do I put this code

```
IntercomSettings.userInfo = function(user, info) {
// add properties to the info object, for instance:
if (user.services.google) {
   info.email = user.services.google.email;
   info['Name'] = user.services.google.given_name + ' ' +    user.services.google.family_name;
   }
}
```

in order to get the info of users logged into say, Google? Can I do the same with FB, LinkedIn etc?

Secondly, how do I get the info of users logged into my app sent to intercom? (I'm getting the userId , location, last page visited)

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So, I got this sorted. Put the following in client/lib/main.js....

```
IntercomSettings.userInfo = function(user, info) {
    info.email = Meteor.user().emails[0].address;
    info['name'] = Meteor.user().username;
};
```